# Does HTML 'body' tag have an onblur event?

Tags: javascript, html, onblur

I tried to bind the `onblur` event to a `<body>` tag and it works in IE 6/8.

However, when I turn to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_body.asp), it turns out that the `<body>` tag doesn't have an `onblur` event.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: probably http://www.w3fools.com knows the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.1) does not list the `onblur` attribute.

The [HTML5 draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-body-element) on the other hand does.

Comment: @Foredoomed: Then you have your answer. Officially, `body` does not have it. Browsers might still support it (like IE seems to do).

Comment: Weirdly, while in HTML5 the `onblur` attribute of the body element works as a shorthand for setting `window.onblur`, using `addEventListener` on the body does not.  (This is mentioned in the spec.)

Answer (score 2):

`body:onblur` is part of the HTML5 spec, but not part of the HTML4 spec.

If you want to support HTML4 browsers, why not use `window:onblur`? For most cases, you'll have the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I would never rely on the source you mentioned. The problem is, MSIE fires the `blur` event for almost *every* element, `<body` included. Wheres most other implementations do the exact oposite.

It might help if you explicitly the a `tabIndex` for the `body element`, for instance:

```
document.body.tabIndex = 1;
document.body.onblur = function() {
    alert('body blur');
};
```

That works for me on FF5. That said, I'm not sure how many versions from FF and how much implementations support that 'tricky' workaround.

The next logical question is, why would you want to fire the `body` a blur event ? The only reasonable thing I can think of, is that you want to know when someone leaves your page ? If that is the case, I would recommend to watch the `window` itself instead of the body.

```
window.onblur = function() {
    alert('window blur');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I have a page which consists of four iframes. The requirement is once the focus leaves from one iframe to another, something needs to be hidden.